# Asp.net deployment process

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-deployment, setup-deployment

I would like to know the process for asp.net web application deployment.

The current approach is described below,

1. Take the latest version of source code to local system (Visual Studio) from the TFS,
2. Clean and Rebuild the application from Visual Studio,
3. Once the build is successful, copy the bin folder content and paste it in "Package Folder"
4. Database change script is generated using schema compare,
5. Once, the schema compare script is generated then the script file is moved to "Package Folder"
6. Configuration files in the "Package Folder" for the asp.net applications is modified as per the environment (QA, UAT, PROD)
7. Finally, "Package Folder" is shared to deployment team for deployment.

I'm not much aware of the deployments so I would like to know, how actually the deployment process happens for enterprise application.

how the version of changes are maintained in the TFS, whether the packages are stored in TFS? and how the source code and database of the particular release maintained in TFS?

If you can share me process then it will be more helpful. And also, can you share me the manual approach for the build process since we don't access to QA and Prod servers and these are handled by different team.

Technology Used:

1. Asp.Net & SQL Server
2. WCF Service

Comment: There's copious documentation of possible approaches / strategies online, a lot published by Microsoft. DevOps advocated automated build and deployment tools, other people just press Publish on their projects and deploy them to the server, and run any accompanying SQL changes as a series of modification scripts. Depends on the level of complexity you require and are prepared to engineer and support

Comment: You don't really need to store your compiled code in source control normally, since they can always be rebuilt from the source, but SQL change scripts are often stored since they are not compiled. You can maintain a particular release's codebase by creating a branch for that release into which you can make any bugfixes etc specific to that release without affecting other ongoing development. This is a broad topic and there are many ways to approach the various issues and requirements. The only correct answer is "do whatever works best for you"

Comment: Thank you ADyson.

I'm going through the following one and if you have any other please share me.  

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/deploying-web-applications-in-enterprise-scenarios/application-lifecycle-management-from-development-to-production

Comment: Which build are you using, local build or TFS build? And will you use TFS to do the deployment or use some scripts locally? According to your description, sounds like the only usage is source control(code stored) for TFS in your case.  Could you explain more clearly?

Comment: I'll do that. everything on local. like we take the code from source control (TFS) and build the code through visual studio and then take all the files from bin folder for deployment.

Comment: @ps_prakash02 Thanks for the sharing, according to your description, the process is related to local, not related to TFS side. Suggest you to remove TFS tag.